# How to get variable value from other js files in nuxt js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex, nuxt.js

I have a nuxt js project, and make project file directories like below:

```
| -- axiosUtility
       | -- index.js
| -- pages
| -- store
| -- other directories
```

The file of axiosUtility/index.js is below:

```js
/* Create a axios instance with custom headers */
import axios from 'axios';

let myVariable = someVariable //someVariable is the result from    // asynchronous 
//request with axios in some web page component, how can I get 
// variable?
// with vuex?

const myAxios = axios.create({
    headers: {'X-My-Variable': myVariable}
});

export default myAxios;
```

Some web page component get a result from asynchronous request, and I want use the result from another js file(or third party library). Where does I save the result of asynchronous request, and how can I require the result no matter of the changes of route?

Comment: persist the values returned from ajax in vue store.

Answer (score 0):

First, you must export that variable:

```
/* Create a axios instance with custom headers */
import axios from 'axios';

export let myVariable = someVariable
//^^^^ -- added

// ... (all else the same)
```

And **import** it elsewhere, whenever you need it:

```
// from a file at pages/foo.js
import { myVariable } from '../axiosUtility';
```